# Identify old shower stem in 100 year old home

Tags: plumbing, repair, faucet, antique

Every supply shop is stumped. Possible very old American Standard due to its 22 spline broach.  I am also leaning towards Gopher due to similarity of appearance to some seats I found online.

This is the shower:

[image]

The stem is just over 5" (but I don't need one that long) and was chrome decades ago.  The stem is actually good now, but I would like to replace it for appearance purposes.  The washer head on the end of the stem swivels so the seal does not spin with the handle.

[image]

Also mainly need seats, it is 1.125" long and threads were probably 1/2" maybe bigger.  The seat is cracked and leaks through the side.  Threads inside actually look decent even though the seat's threads are shot.  And they are so shot it is hard to guestimate the pitch but I would say 24 if I had to make a guess.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes repair/refurbish is the way to go for antiques. Sometimes, it's better to cut losses and replace. I'm not saying this is a "replace" situation, but do brace yourself for the fact that you may not be able to find parts to refurbish and replacing the entire fixture may be your only option. Then again, don't give up hope yet, there's a fair bit of knowledge floating 'round here!

Comment: Thanks, the tile work is excellent, and the back side is a hallway, no simple way to access it other then a lot of teardown.  If I can't find exact parts I will try a shorter seat, and a stem with longer reach.  I did find 1 possible option, it is a shaft from "Gopher" that seems to fit the stem I have's assembly.

Comment: I found a very similar seat for "Indiana Brass"  9/16-27 thread, and almost as long.  Will update as I keep working on it.